# Kendo-ui dataviz, how to set whitespace on graph

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have this graph:
It's a line graph with width 0, and markers visible.
There is a lot of null data in it.
The most right value is not null,  but because of the amount of items on the X-axis,  the half of the marker is hidden, making it very not-user-friendly.

simplified example:
http://runner.telerik.io/fullscreen/eYoJe

What is the best way, to add some whitespace there?
Adding extra null values is not an option, I don't know the ammount of items on the x-axis. Therefore i would have to calculate how much pixels one value takes, and I really don't want to go that way..

Comment: You have to increase bottom axis range to show one more series than you have in your data. This topic can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807849/kendoui-line-graph-how-to-keep-labels-from-being-drawn-outside-the-graph It's about the labels but you should do it the same way

Comment: @j4ro  Hey,  good try..  didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution:

```
panes: [
    {clip: false}
]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JanDeclercq/fvx41py8/